# Issue with [students-t] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

I've only just really noticed the [students-t](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/students-t) tag.

It has no tag wiki and appears to be being used for both the t-test and the t-distribution (with, at a quick glance, more using it to refer to the test). It is used in fewer posts to refer to the test than [t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-test) and in fewer posts that refer to the distribution than [t-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-distribution). I don't see a clear purpose to it outside those meanings. About 2/3 of its uses have been this year (7 and a bit months); for some reason it seems suddenly popular.

My suggestion: I think (i) any references to Student's t-distribution under `[students-t]` should be changed to `[t-distribution]`; and then (ii) `[students-t]` should become a synonym of `[t-test]`.

Given that it involves more than a handful of changes and its total number of uses is about the same as for `[t-test]`, I thought I should ask for views on this before doing anything hasty. What do you think?

(I haven't yet checked if I have enough answers in the right tags to do all these steps myself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(+1, *I thought I had asked about this on meta a while ago, but evidently I didn't.*)

I agree, I see no reason for the existence of the `[students-t]` tag.  (I just edited its excerpt to note this.)  I think starting to re-tag those instances where it is used to refer to the distribution is a good idea / first step.  Since there are several such cases, my recommendation would be to do 2-3 at a time, several hours apart so as not to flood the main page.  I did the same thing a few weeks ago w/ the ambiguous `[fisher]` tag.  (You may even want to re-tag those instances where it refers to the test, but you could do that second--or not at all.)  These re-taggings should really be done *before* the tag is made a synonym for `[t-test]`, or those threads will become mis-tagged and the situation will be much more difficult to rectify.

Comment: +1 I agree that the retagging needs to happen first.